# rxAndroid manipulate data to get List

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I need to show a list of games in a RecyclerView.
problem is the data structure. I have teams (the name of the team should be a header in a list that includes only a photo) and under it more Game object from the "game" array inside every team array.
I call the api with Observable retrofit call:

```
 RestManager.get()
        .api()
        .getLastGames(params...)
        .compose(Transformer.applyIO))      
.subscribe(listener::LastGameDataReady));
```

the JSON i get from the server looks as follow:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kRqf.png)
how do I edit the response to get `List<Game>` to the subscribe interface instead of the total ResponseObject

Answer (score 0):

> how do I edit the response to get List to the subscribe
>   interface instead of the total ResponseObject

you could use the [map](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html) operator for that, which task is transform the emitted item of an `Observable`

```
RestManager.get()
    .api()
    .getLastGames(params...)
    .compose(Transformer.applyIO))    
    .map(responseObj -> // extract and return your list) 
    .subscribe(listener::LastGameDataReady));
```

if the only parameter of `LastGameDataReady` is a `List<>` of the same type returned in the map operator, you can still use the `::` operator

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get `List<Game>` from this JSON response I'll suggest you to use `concatMap` to extract games lists and later `toList` to merge them back.

```
RestManager.get()
        .api()
        .getLastGames(params...)
        .concatMap(Observable::from)
        .concatMap(team -> Observable.from(team.getGames()))
        .toList()
        .compose(Transformer.applyIO))      
.subscribe(listener::LastGameDataReady));
```